# page title different from displayed title html/md

Tags: html, css

I have a simple web page written in markdown where the title looks like this:

```
---
title: <h1 class="side">Text Title | </h1><h3 class="side">Text Subtitle</h3>
---
```

In the body of the page it displays correctly, but it shows the formatting in areas like the tab bar of the browser. I'd like to find a way to keep the formatting without having it displayed.

Just to be clear, the `class="side"` is a css `<style>` to display the headings inline, and the page is processed into html with the following result:

```
<title><h1 class="side">Text Title | </h1><h3 class="side">Text Subtitle</h3></title>
```

and the area in the body where the title is correctly displayed looks like this:

```
<header>
    <h1>{{ page.title }}</h1>
</header>
```

Comment: The `<title>` can only appear once per page, in the `<head>` using it outside of that, it will be an error. `<head>` and `<header>` are two very different tags

Comment: Do I understand you correctly that you want to use a `page.title` variable that contains a string that includes html tags.  And you want to use this variable both in the `<title>` element (in the head) and the `<h1>` element (in the body)?  If so, you CAN'T.  In the head, it will be displayed as a pure string, as you described.

Comment: @Steve You understood me correctly, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have HTML within a [title](http://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/TITLE.html) element.

If your title is stored somewhere and written out via server-side code, you will need to change your server side code to somehow strip the HTML.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot style the `<title>` element - and using it outside the `<head></head>` is invalid HTML/XHTML

[More info from the w3c](http://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/TITLE.html)